# Android 11 - If you turn off your screen with an app open that uses data, will any data/battery used be considered background?

Tags: battery, screen, mobile-data

Let's say I open Pokemon go and was using mobile data to play it and kept the app open but turned off my screen.

For the next few hours, I know battery and data usage will be significantly reduced, but during this time will any battery and data used be only considered "background usage?"

It's impossible for an app to use "foreground data and battery" if the screen is turned off?

Comment: To my knowledge all apps are considered to be in background when screen is off no matter which app was on top when you switched off screen.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! To make sure this is clear you're saying if you check foreground and background data usage, any data used while the screen is off when any app on top of the screen was opened, usage would ONLY show up in "background?"